# Override a JS function in Odoo 12

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, odoo, odoo-12

I'm working with Odoo V12 and I need to override a function defined in a JS file and inject some code inside this function for changing a variable value.

The funcion I need to override is this one:

```
odoo.define('portal.signature_form', function (require){
    "use strict";

    require('web_editor.ready');

    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    var base = require('web_editor.base');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var Widget = require("web.Widget");
    var rpc = require("web.rpc");

    var qweb = core.qweb;

    var SignatureForm = Widget.extend({
        template: 'portal.portal_signature',
        events: {
            'click #o_portal_sign_clear': 'clearSign',
            'click .o_portal_sign_submit': 'submitSign',
            'init #o_portal_sign_accept': 'initSign',
        },
    // some defined events
        submitSign: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            // some code
            return rpc.query({
                route: this.options.callUrl,          <------------------
                params: {
                    'res_id': this.options.resId,
                    'access_token': this.options.accessToken,
                    'partner_name': partner_name,
                    'signature': signature ? signature[1] : false,
                },
            }).then(function (data) {
            // mode code
```

The objetive is to obtain a custom value and replace it for "route" variable.

I have defined my own JS file for doing it, first of all linking this file in a XML template and then writing my code, but I'm not able to modify the variable commented before.
[image]

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is patching the existing `SignatureForm` widget, instead of inheriting the new widget, which `extend` function do. Odoo provides way to patch existing JS class, the `include` function, more details in the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class).

Another thing you are getting wrong here is that, `route` is not a variable, but a `property` of the object provided to the `rpc.query` function, and to change that, you have to patch the `submitSign` function. You can follow this:

```
signature_form.SignatureForm.include({
  submitSign: function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            // some code
            return rpc.query({
                route: "your value",          <------------------
                params: {
                    'res_id': this.options.resId,
                    'access_token': this.options.accessToken,
                    'partner_name': partner_name,
                    'signature': signature ? signature[1] : false,
                },
            }).then(function (data) {
            // mode code
})
```

Assuming that `SignatureForm` is returned inside an object at the end of the main file.